# Return SQL rows that don't match from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns:

1. **AccountID**
2. **HH_Num**
3. **RepCode**

I need a way to see the rows where any `HH_Num` is the same, but the `RepCode` is different.

Example:

```
Account ID  HH_Num    RepCode
1234        10000     SS01
1235        10000     SS01
1236        10000     SS01
1237        10000     PO45
1238        50000     UY01
1239        50000     UY01
1241        50000     UY75
```

So my query need to return the rows wherethe `HH_Num` = the same as other data, but `RepCode` does NOT match..... Any thoughts?????
Hint: My query should return 2 results since they have the same `HH_Num` but different `RepCodes`?????

Comment: Please tag specifically what DB are you using.

Comment: I did... It is a SQL DB. Also, I added a pic since the wording did not come out right.

Comment: Please add expected output.

Comment: Mysql and sql server are two different products with slightly different syntax. Which one do you use? Pls also share what you have tried to solve the issue and what was wrong with the attempt.

Comment: SQL not MySQL.... I have tried many things, but Ned help. Maybe if I saw the correct way I would get it.

Comment: MySql ***IS*** SQL. So is Sql Server. They are different dialects of SQL database. If you mean Sql Server, you say "Sql Server" (and use the `sql-server` tag), not just SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select DISTINCT HH_Num, RefCode 
from yourtable
```

Comment: According to this "
I have a table with 3 columns:

AccountID
HH_Num
RepCode
I need a way to see the rows where any HH_Num is the same, but the RepCode is different." you dont have a choice except to use distinct